# How to duplicate a MySQL table, including indexes and data using workbench?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have a large amount of data in my table and I need that same table with different name but same data and structure.

I'm using workbench for this because it is faster than phpmyadmin.

How can I copy table data and structure using workbench?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute:

`CREATE TABLE newtablename SELECT * FROM sourcetablename`